# How can I find a second space character in a string using indexOf in Java?

Tags: java, indexof

My problem is as follows:

> Assume that sentence is a variable of type String that has been assigned a value. Assume furthermore that this value is a String consisting of words separated by single space characters with a period at the end. For example: "This is a possible value of sentence."

> Assume that there is another variable declared, secondWord, also of type String. Write the statements needed so that the second word of the value of sentence is assigned to secondWord. So, if the value of sentence were "Broccoli is delicious." your code would assign the value "is" to secondWord.

I have written the following code:

`secondWord = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(" ", sentence.indexOf(" "+1)));`

I have no idea what I'm doing so I would appreciate any explanation of what I should do. Keep in mind I'm very new to coding and I can't use things like loop. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than trying to do everything in one line, it's usually easier to understand your own code by assigning the intermediate work to variables.  Like `int firstSpaceIndex = sentence.indexOf(" ")`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could split the sentence into "parts" using `String.split(" ")` which will give you an array of the words.

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
String secondWord = words[1];   //0 based
```

Watch out for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the words `String` array has a length less than 2

Comment: You could add a if (words.length >= 2 ) check and then assign the secondWord var to prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: tried this, the in broswer IDE we use in class refused to let me submit this. appreciate it tho

Answer (score 0):

If you must use indexOf,just like this:

```
sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(" ") + 1, sentence.indexOf(" ", sentence.indexOf(" ") + 1));
```

But the better way is what like @tomgeraghty3

Comment: worked! got a friend to explain it to me, so i understand as well. Thank you!